# Redirecting after a successful (or otherwise) login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect

I'm relatively new to Rails, so I've been following Railscasts to get up to speed, and have successfully created a Login function. The code is as follows:

```
def create

    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        if params[:remember_me]
          cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        else
          cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        end
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"

      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
        render "new"
      end

  end
```

However, as the code shows, the user is always redirected to the home page, as indicated by `root_url`.

What I'd like to achieve is something along the following lines:

1. The user is on the "About", "Contact" or whatever page
2. The user clicks the "Login" link and is taken to the login form page
3. After successfully (or unsuccessfully) logging in, the user is
   returned to the "About", "Contact" page or whatever.

However, I cannot seem to work out what I should replace `root_url` with. I tried `request.referer`, but this obviously took me back to the login form (or, rather, a message stating I was already logged in) rather than the page that the user originally accessed the login form from.

I suppose I could do some sort of switch/case, where I store the referring page in a string or whatever, and redirect back to that, but this sounds a bit clunky and (as with most things Rails) I'm sure there's an easier way that I'm missing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store return_to in session you can refer [here](http://railspikes.com/2008/5/1/quick-tip-store_location-with-subdomains),[here](http://www.rorexperts.com/redirect-back-or-default-in-rails-t1969.html)